# Show a string of certain length without truncating

Tags: html, ruby, string, slice

I am displaying a string of certain length in ruby. only 80 characters of that string can be displayed in one line. for example if string length is 82 then it will be shown in 2 lines if length is 250 then string will be shown in 5 lines etc and i want to split on whitespace not the word.

I am new in this so don't know how can i solve this.

Comment: If `n = str.size` is the length of your string, calculate `m, r = n.divmod(80)`, then `m.times { |i| puts str[80*i, 80] }; puts str[-r..-1] if r > 0`. See [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod) and [String#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: Do you care were to split the string – for example only at whitespaces? Or is it okay to split words somewhere in the middle?

Comment: No, i want to split the word only at whitespaces

Comment: You should edit your question to incorporate the informtion in your comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def wrap(str, max_line_len)
  str.scan /(?<=\A| ).{1,#{max_line_len}}(?= |\z)/
end
```

```
str = "Little Miss Muffet she sat on her tuffet, eating her curds and whey. Along " + 
      "came a spider who sat down beside her and frightened Miss Muffet away."
```

```
         1         2         3    
123456789012345678901234567890123
```

```
puts wrap(str, 31)
Little Miss Muffet she sat on
her tuffet, eating her curds
and whey. Along came a spider
who sat down beside her and
frightened Miss Muffet away.
```

```
puts wrap(str, 32)
Little Miss Muffet she sat on
her tuffet, eating her curds and
whey. Along came a spider who
sat down beside her and
frightened Miss Muffet away.
```

```
puts wrap(str, 33)
Little Miss Muffet she sat on her
tuffet, eating her curds and
whey. Along came a spider who sat
down beside her and frightened
Miss Muffet away.
```

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan). The regular expression reads, "match between `1` and `max_line_len` characters, immediately preceded by the beginning of the string or a space and immediately followed by a space or the end of the string". `(?<=\A| )` is a *positive lookbehind* and `(?= |\z)` is a *positive lookahead*.

Comment: Clean concise and works perfectly. Even if I'm a dunce with regex! :))

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
loop.inject([[], input]) do |(acc, src)|
  if m = src[/.{1,79}(\s|\z)/]
    [acc << m, $']
  else
    break acc << src
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for `loop` returning an enumerator. I've not seen that before. Being an enumerator-fanatic I've tucked it away.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `break acc` and why `79` rather than `80`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland 79 because of trailing space included. `break acc` seems legit, yes. scan does better in any case :)

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and dirty, iterative version:

```
max_chars = 80
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.'

lines = []
words = text.split

while words.length > 0
  line = words.shift

  while words.first && (line.length + words.first.length + 1) <= max_chars
    line << " #{words.shift}" 
  end

  lines << line
end

lines.each { |line|  puts line }
#=> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
#   tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
#   vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
#   no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
#   amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
#   labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
#   et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
#   sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Comment: Why almost nobody choses `loop.inject` instead of this `while` which requires the local variables to be declared in the outer scope? :)

Answer (score 0):

Other option, not so clean, but...

The idea is to find the index of the spaces and substitute with `\n` the spaces at index close to the line length.

So, given the string `str` and the `max_len`:

```
delta = 0
(str + " ")
.each_char.with_index.with_object([]) { |(c, i), o| o << i if c == " "} # find the index of the spaces
.each_cons(2).with_object([]) do |(a, b), tmp| # select the index to be substituted
  if b > (tmp.size + 1) * max_len + delta
    tmp << a 
    delta = tmp.last - max_len * tmp.size + 1
  end
end.each { |i| str[i] = "\n" } # substitute
```

Now `str` has `\n` when line length is close to `max_len`.
This alterates the original string.