# Requesting an insight on reduce ruby code

Tags: ruby, algorithm, reduce

I started solving exercises in hackerrank in the enumerable section. 
   The exercise asks to complete the sum method which takes an integer n and returns the sum to the n terms of the series. I found the solution from another source but I don't quite understand how the reduce works in this case and the output.

```
def sum_terms(n)
  series = []

  1.upto(n) do |i|
    series.push(i ** 2 + 1)
  end

  series.reduce(0, :+)
end

puts sum_terms(5)
# outputs 60
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand? Have you looked at the `reduce` docs (and any related tutorials)? Do you know what `:+` means? Once you have those ideas down it should be pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 3):

We can write this method as follows:

```
def sum_terms(n)
  arr = create_series(n)
  arr.reduce(0, :+)
end

def create_series(n)
  series = []  
  1.upto(n) do |i|
    series.push(i**2 + 1)
  end
  series
end
```

```
sum_terms(5)
  #=> 60
```

The steps are as follows:

```
n = 5
arr = create_series(n)
  #=> [2, 5, 10, 17, 26] 
arr.reduce(0, :+)
  #=> 60
```

Let's first look at the method `create_series`. This method returns an array of `n` elements, those elements being a *mapping* of the integers `1`, `2`,...,`n`. "Mapping" suggests that it would be more sensible to use the method [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) than creating an empty array (`series`), appending `n` elements to it and returning that array:

```
def create_series(n)
  1.upto(n).map do |i|
    i**2 + 1
  end
end
```

```
create_series(5)
  #=> [2, 5, 10, 17, 26]
```

Because `map`'s block is so brief we'd probably write it with braces rather than `do..end`:

```
def create_series(n)
  1.upto(n).map { |i| i**2 + 1 }
end
```

Now let's look at the method `sum_terms`. For `n = 5`, this becomes:

```
[2, 5, 10, 17, 26].reduce(0, :+) #=> 60
```

which is the shorthand version of:

```
[2, 5, 10, 17, 26].reduce(0) { |tot,x| tot + x) #=> 60
```

Here I am using the form of [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) that takes an argument (`0`), which is the initial value of of the block variable `tot`. When the first element of the array that is `reduce`'s receiver (`2`) is passed to `map`'s block, the block variable `x` is set equal to that value. The block calculation is then performed:

```
tot + n
  #=> 0 + 2 => 2
```

The value of `tot` (`0`) is now replaced with that sum (`2`). Specifically, the value of the *memo* (here `tot`) is set equal to the *last calculation performed* in the block. Next, the element `5` of the receiver is passed to the block and `x` is set equal to it. The block calculation is now:

```
tot + n
  #=> 2 + 5 => 7
```

and `tot` is set equal to `7`. This is repeated thrice more, causing `tot` to successively equal `17`, `34` and `60`. As there are then no more elements to pass to the receiver the block returns the final value of `tot`, `60`.

Now consider the following:

```
[2, 5, 10, 17, 26].reduce(:+)                   #=> 60
```

which is shorthand for:

```
[2, 5, 10, 17, 26].reduce { |tot,x| tot + x }   #=> 60
```

This differs from the first calculation in that `reduce` does not have an argument. As explained in the documentation, in this case `tot` is initially set equal to the first value of the receiver, `2`, and then each of the four remaining elements of the receiver is passed to the block, causing `tot` to successively equal `7`, `17`, `34` and `60`.

Clearly both forms of `reduce` give the same result in this case<sup>1</sup>.

We can improve on this code, however, by skipping the calculation of array `[2, 5, 10, 17, 26]` as follows:

```
1.upto(5).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot + i**2 + 1 }  #=> 60
```

Notice that `reduce` *must* have an argument of zero here, as

```
1.upto(5).reduce { |tot,i| tot + i**2 + 1 }     #=> 59
```

is equivalent to:

```
1 + 2.upto(5).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot + i**2 + 1 }
```

which is incorrect.

A simpler way of performing this calculation is to use the method [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum), which made its debut in Ruby v2.4:

```
1.upto(5).sum { |i| i**2 + 1 }                  #=> 60
```

Yet simpler is to evaluate *Faulhaber's formula*:

```
n = 5
n + n*(n + 1)*(2*n + 1)/6                       #=> 60
```

<sup>1 There are situations `reduce` is assigned an argument (often zero) merely to deal with a so-called *edge case*. Suppose, for example, we wished to sum the elements of an array `arr` and add that to `10`. We could write `10 + arr.reduce(:+)` which works fine as long as `arr` is not empty. `10 + [].reduce(:+)` raises an exception, however, as `[].reduce(:+) #=> nil`. By contrast, `10 + [].reduce(0, :+) #=> 10`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but you should [see documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) for how to use [reduce](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce)

But a simplified version in your use case is just that it sums the integers in the array.  You also don't need to pass `0` as a first argument so you can just do:

```
series.reduce(:+) # instead of series.reduce(0, :+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `reduce` performs an operation on every element in the `series` array. It takes two arguments. 
The operation is defined by the second argument (in this case it's a symbol that names the plus operator `:+`). Therefore all elements are added to each other. The first argument specifies an initial value.
You can read more about this here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

Answer (score 0):

This is an absolutely legit question, because unlike *all* other methods in `Enumerable` accepting a block, `reduce` (and `inject` as its alias) has a weird “short” notation, accepting a method name as a second argument without `&`.

So, if it was *literally any* other method, accepting a block, it was written as `series.reduce(0, &:+)`.

Which is a shorthand to `series.reduce(0) { |e, acc| e + acc }`.

---

*Sidenote:* the code is extremely not ruby idiomatic, I’d rewrite it like

```
def sum_terms(n)
  1.upto(n).map do |i|
    i ** 2 + 1
  end.reduce(0, &:+)
end
```

Comment: Why the extra step, though? Ditch the map and calculate in the reducer. Also can omit the default value.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did not want to drastically modify the code, I wanted to rewrite _same_ steps in ruby way. Those who rely on the first element as an accumulator initial value should be burned in hell :)

Comment: "should be burned in hell" - huh? You only need to specify the initial memo if shape of your memo is radically different from that of the elements. That is, you reduce a sequence of integers into a hash, or something like that. If shape is the same, it shouldn't make any difference. In fact, I challenge you to produce a snippet of code which works with specified initial memo, but breaks with default. :)

Comment: Challenge accepted https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442860/2035262 Please note there in no default _at all_.

Comment: What do you mean, no default? It's there. You meant _no collection_? Nice snippet, I got a mild headache and a TIL out of it, thanks :) But do you have one with a collection?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev no collection means no first element (aka default.) Any functional-style map is implemented as `foldl` aka `reduce`: `[1,2,3].reduce([]) { |acc, e| acc << e * 2 }`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I'm on your side here: 1). Educating the asker and other readers is job #1. Here that means explaining that it's better to perform the calculation in one step, using `reduce`, or better, `sum`, as that can be easily done after explaining how the method shown works; 2) I don't like adding any unnecessary bits, whether it be an unneeded initial value for `reduce` or `self.` when it's not necessary, as those actions cause readers to waste precious seconds asking themselves, "Hmm, now why is that there? I'm sure Aleksei would have a reason. I better look more deeply..."

Comment: @CarySwoveland sure I would. `[].reduce(:+) #⇒ nil` vs. `[].reduce(0, :+) #⇒ 0` and `nil` is an inconsistent behaviour for reducing array of integers (say, if those are prices for goods or something business-related.)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ⇑ it’s always better to be consistent amongst applications. Summing prices of zero products should not result in `nil`. And Matz is kinda in agreement with me here `[].sum #⇒ 0`.