# fill hash values with another hash

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with values with more values:

```
hash1 = {
  :a => {
    :foo => 435,
    :bar => 3264
  },
  :b => {
    :foo => 45234,
    :bar => 2452
  },
  :c => {
    :foo => 4352,
    :bar => 4535
  }
}
```

and I need to add the sum of a, b, and c to new array

```
hash2 = {
  :a => total,
  :b => total,
  :c => total
}
```

my attempt so far is something like:
    `hash2.each {|e,v| v = hash1[0]}`

struggling so I need some help! thanks!

Comment: `hash1.transform_values { |v| v.values.sum }`

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin works only on ruby version >= 2.4

Comment: @lacostenycoder it’s 2019 all around; if somebody asks such question it clearly means they do not support legacy behemoth and can have the up-to-date ruby version installed.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, its true, im up-to-date

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Ruby version >= 2.4 you can do

```
hash2 = hash1.transform_values { |v| v.values.sum }
=>{:a=>3699, :b=>47686, :c=>8887}
```

UPDATED thanks to @3limin4t0r, and @Aleksei Matiushkin for a cleaner way for Ruby version < 2.4 see comment

```
hash2 = Hash[hash1.map { |k, v| [k, v.values.reduce(0, &:+)] }]
=> {:a=>3699, :b=>47686, :c=>8887}
# or if your prefer each_with_object
hash1.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v.values.reduce(0, &:+) }
=> {:a=>3699, :b=>47686, :c=>8887}
```

Original left here for conversation

Otherwise you can do this, there's probably a quicker way but it works

```
hash2 = {}
sum_vals = hash1.values.map{|h| h.values.inject(&:+)}
hash1.keys.each_with_index{|key, i| hash2[key] = sum_vals[i] }
hash2
=>{:a=>3699, :b=>47686, :c=>8887}
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r tried that and got `NoMethodError: undefined method `sum' for [435, 3264]:Array` on ruby 2.0.0.  Same on version 2.3.6

Comment: @3limin4t0r your last comment doesn't work either, are you testing this before commenting?

Comment: Also keep in mind that your `.inject(&:+)` returns `nil` and not `0` for empty arrays.

Comment: @3limin4t0r `NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for [[:a, 3699], [:b, 47686], [:c, 8887]]:Array` for your previous comment in ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197889/discussion-between-lacostenycoder-and-3limin4t0r).

Comment: For older versions I'd use `Hash[hash1.map { |k, v| [k, v.values.reduce(0, :+)] }]`

Comment: @3limin4t0r `hash1.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v.values.reduce(0, &:+) }`is way cleaner.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin let's clean it up more even more `hash1.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v.values.reduce(:+) }`

Comment: @engineersmnky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441885/requesting-an-insight-on-reduce-ruby-code/57442702?noredirect=1#comment101447426_57442702 — I do always explicitly specify the initial value _and_ the ampersand to clarify the intent (passing block.) `reduce` and `inject` accepting a symbol is plain wrong.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin while I can concede to the fact that passing a symbol to `reduce` does leave one feeling kind of dirty :).  All of the answers are already founded on the basis of the given structure so IMO the initial value is neither here nor there. What if `v` was not a `Hash` then the result of the `values` message is indeterminate and `sum` or `reduce` even more so . For example should `values` actually result in an `Array<String>` or `Array<Array>` then `reduce(0,&:+)` will raise `TypeError` (as would `sum`) but `reduce(&:+)` would not.

Comment: @engineersmnky I agree with both sides of the debate here. Sometimes the flexibility in ruby leads to these interesting conversations. On one side we have "when in doubt, leave it out" the other,  "to begin, leave it in".  In this example we are operating on a specific value where the hash structure is known, so we often look for the shortest solution.  Does the 2.4 + version introduce any of this discussion?

Comment: @lacostenycoder it operates on the same assumptions with less flexibility. `sum` assumes `Integer` and will require an initial value unless the `obj.all?(Numeric)`. This means that to leverage sum with something other than numbers you most know what that something is and/or pass a block to convert that something (essentially `map(&method).sum(initial)`) for instance `{foo: 1, bar: 2}.sum(&:pop) #=> 3` however  `{foo: 1, bar: 2}.sum("",&:to_s) #=>  "[:foo, 1][:bar, 2]"` or `{foo: 1, bar: 2}.sum([]) #=> [:foo,1,:bar,2]`

Comment: Additionally `reduce` can form any kind of reduction where as `sum`(by virtue of its name) is specific to `+` meaning that each return must `respond_to?(:+)` and accept `enum.next` as a valid argument to `+` and return an object that does the same until such point as `enum.next` raises `StopIteration`

Comment: @engineersmnky wow, I had no idea about `{foo: 1, bar: 2}.sum(&:pop)` or that `.sum` could be called on `Hash` but since it is a kind of `Array` that makes sense. That is very interesting. I have learned a lot by having had the good fortune of testing Aleksei Matiushkin 's comment in an older version of Ruby.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yea Aleksei Matiushkin is completely right. `transform_values` has a destructive version as well as a non destructive version. The destructive version has what is called a bang, or an exclamation point, so this: `transform_values!` is read as transform values bang, and it will alter your original hash. On the other hand `transform_values` returns a new array without altering the original, hence, non destructive. From what I can tell you want to deal with the non destructive version.

In this case you can run a `hash1.transform_values { |values| values.values.sum }` which will return the new hash, however, because this is nondestructive, `hash1` will still be equal to your original `hash1`. Because of this you want to set `hash2` equal to the transform values.

Basically what is happening is the hash is running through all the values associated with the keys and taking those keys values (due to you having a multidimensional hash) and adding them together.

Here is a great link for you to take a look at! https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/06/14/ruby-2-4-added-hash-transform-values-and-its-destructive-version-from-active-support.html

Comment: Nice but it is not supported in Ruby version < 2.4