# Is there a more elegant way of writing a while loop in Ruby where the array size is not known?

Tags: ruby

Using the following example:

```
array = [1,20]

new_array = []
i = array[0]


while i < array[1]
  new_array.push(i)
  i+= 2
end

#new_array = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this loop without have to write an empty array (`new_array`) and an external variable loop counter (`i`)? I was thinking something along the lines of `new_array.map{|x| }` but instead of iterating through each element, it continually adds a number until it hits a certain limit.

Comment: The first array is sort of pointless.

Comment: `(1..10).map { |n| 2*n-1 }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to create an array of odd numbers up to a limit, you can use a range with a step.

```
limit = 20 
array = (1..limit).step(2).to_a
```

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to descend as well as ascend you can use `step`.

```
#Ascending 
start = 1 
limit = 20 

array = start.step(limit, 2).to_a

#Descending 
start = 20 
limit = 1 

array = start.step(limit, -2).to_a
```

Comment: Is there any way to subtract using this method? When I try doing `(20..3).step(-2).to_a`, I get an ArgumentError. Just using this problem as an abstraction for another problem I'm having, and I'd like to subtract as well as add from a range.

Comment: So in that case, if the limits are 20 and 3 you would want `[20, 18, 16, ...]`?

Comment: Yes that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having an alternative, you could also select ([Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)) odds numbers ([Integer#odds?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F)) out of your [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html):

```
(1..20).select(&:odd?)
#=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is addressed to the question stated in the title, not to the particular example presenteed.

Suppose the user is asked to enter a sequence of strings, with an empty string signifying that the user is finished. These strings are to be saved in an array which is to be returned.

This is a typical way of writing the code using a `while` loop:

```
def gettem
  arr = []
  until (s = gets.chomp).empty? do
    arr << s
  end
  arr
end
```

One could instead use [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and the keyword `break`, which some (including me) prefer to `while` and `until` loops.

```
def gettem
  arr = []
  loop do
    s = gets.chomp
    break if s.empty?
    arr << s
  end
  arr
end
```

A third way, suggested by @Aleksei Matiushkin in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57440279/show-a-string-of-certain-length-without-truncating/57444089#57444089) (which I had not seen before) is the following:

```
def gettem
  loop.with_object([]) do |_,arr|
    s = gets.chomp
    break arr if s.empty?
    arr << s
  end
end
```

This uses the form of `loop` that returns an enumerator (see the doc). If I run this and enter `"dog"`, `"cat"` and `"\n"`, the return value is `["dog", "cat"]`, as desired.

This approach has three of advantages over the other approaches:

- the variable `arr` is confined to the block, away from prying eyes;
- fewer lines of code are needed; and
- the return value can be chained, as illustrated below.

```
def gettem
  loop.with_object([]) do |_,arr|
    s = gets.chomp
    break arr if s.empty?
    arr << s
  end.then { |arr| [arr.size, arr] }
end
```

When executing this method and entering `"dog"`, `"cat"` and `"\n"`, the array `[2, ["dog", "cat"]]` is returned.

I've used an underscore for the first block variable (which always has a value of `nil`) to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.